# Why does Django use salt in hmac?

Tags: django, cryptography, hmac

Django `salted_hmac()` add salt to `settings.SECRET_KEY`.
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/crypto.py#L29

And, it says `A different key_salt should be passed in for every application of HMAC.`.

Why do we need to use different key_salt in for every application?

Comment: Maybe to provide [semantic security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security)? What is it supposed to be used for?

Comment: It is used for signing for cookie, and session. However, using salt don't improve semantic security, I think. https://github.com/django/django/blob/53ccffdb8c8e47a4d4304df453d8c79a9be295ab/django/contrib/messages/storage/cookie.py#L127